# how to transpose a matrix in r if the usual `t( )` doesn't work?

Tags: r, matrix, transpose

I have a matrix I am trying to transpose in R but the t() function does not return the right answer. How can I transpose the matrix?

```
> xx=matrix(c(3,7,4,8),2,byrow=TRUE)
> xx
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,]    3     7
[2,]    4     8
> t(xx)
[1] 0.7071068 0.7071068
```

Comment: Have you redefined the `t` function in your workspace?

Comment: i.e. as something like `t <- function(...) rep(sqrt(.5), 2)`

Comment: Similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12019678

Comment: No I haven't, I don't know why its not working...

Comment: Show us the output of `methods(t)`

Comment: Thanks to you all, the problem has been solved now....:)..I used rm() function

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - That's a ridiculous suggestion... nobody would write that function... Clearly it was `t <- function(x){apply(x, 2, sd)}
`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien : why did you delete your answer?  Looked good to me ..

Comment: @BenBolker -- 'cause it was wrong -- both parts of it! (That said, I'll undelete it: (a) as a monument to the stupidity of **guarantee**ing anything; and (b) because it's wrong in interesting ways.)

Answer (score 12):

**This answer is incorrect, but in ways that were enlightening to me and might be to others, so I'll leave it up.**

As @mnel noted, the base R function `t()` must be masked by another function of the same name.  Try removing the function `t()` and doing `t(xx)` again. I guarantee you'll get the correct results.

What do you get when you run this:

```
rm(t)
t(xx)
```

If (despite my guarantee!) it still doesn't work, you can fully specify the version of `t()` you want to use, like this:

```
base::t(xx)
```

---

**Here's why the two suggestions above are insufficient**

From `?UseMethod`:

> Namespaces can register methods for generic functions.  To support
>   this, ‘UseMethod’ and ‘NextMethod’ search for methods in two places:
>   **first in the environment in which the generic function is called**, and
>   then in the registration data base for the environment in which the
>   generic is defined (typically a namespace).  So methods for a generic
>   function need to be available in the environment of the call to the
>   generic, or they must be registered.  (It does not matter whether they
>   are visible in the environment in which the generic is defined.)

I wrongly assumed that S3 method dispatch looks for methods like `t.default()` *first* in  `base:::.__S3MethodsTable__.` and *then* perhaps in `asNamespace("base")`*before* looking in the calling environment, whereas the reverse is closer to the truth.

---

**Edit from GSee**

Here's an interactive session to demonstrate what could have been the problem.

```
> t <- function(x, ...) print("generic masked")
> t.default <- function(x, ...) print("t.default masked")
> t.matrix <- function(x, ...) print("t.matrix was used")
> t.numeric <- function(x, ...) print("t.numeric was used")
> xx=matrix(c(3,7,4,8),2,byrow=TRUE)
> t(xx)
[1] "generic masked"
> base::t(xx)
[1] "t.matrix was used"
> rm(t.matrix)
> base::t(xx)
[1] "t.numeric was used"
> rm(t.numeric)
> base::t(xx)
[1] "t.default masked"
> rm(t.default)
> base::t(xx)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    7    8
```

Comment: That doesn't help if `t.default` is masked... or if there is a `t.matrix` method defined. ;-)

Comment: @GSee -- It should help. `base::t(xx)` should look first in `asNamespace("base")`, where it'll find `t.default()` even if a function of the same name is registered elsewhere, right?

Comment: No. methods defined in your globalenv() are used first.

Comment: Thank you both, but actually i am trying to generate a chi-square plot. The function i defined is qqplot<-function (xx)
 {

 n=length(xx[,1]);p=length(xx[1,])
 xbar=colMeans(as.data.frame(xx));ss=var(xx)
 ssinv=solve(ss);d2=c()
 for (i in (1:n)){
         xi=cbind(xx[i,]-xbar)
         d2=c(d2,t(xi)%*%ssinv%*%xi)
         }
 q=qchisq(((1:n)-0.5)/n,p)
 
plot(q,sort(d2),type="p",pch=20,col="red",xlab="q",ylab="d^2",main="Chi-squa
 re Quantile Plot")
 }

Comment: +1 for that point of widsom from Gsee on searching the globalenv first. Didn't know that.

Comment: @GSee -- Not at all! Thanks for that. I'm also glad Ben nudged me to undelete.

Comment: @user1854786 You're forming bad habits! `qqplot` is also a function in the `stats` package, which is loaded by default. As you've seen, creating functions with existing names can be very confusing; you should avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write your own function:

```
xx <- matrix(c(3,7,4,8), 2, byrow = TRUE)
transp <- function(n){
    TM <- matrix(, nrow = ncol(n), ncol = nrow(n))
        for (i in 1 : nrow(TM)){
            for (j in 1 : ncol(TM)){
                TM[i, j] <- n[j, i]
            }
        }
    print(TM)
} 
transp(xx)
```