# Define `+=` in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment, increment

C and VB.NET (and perhaps some others) have convenient functions for incrementing a variable.  E.g.:

```
x = 3
x +=5
# x now equals 8
```

Is there a way to define such an operator in R?  I've tried:

```
`+=` <- function(x, y){x <<- x + y}
```

but no joy.  That was based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019635/cant-add-constant-to-vector-in-r).

Comment: a slight variation, but could you live with `'%+=%' <- function(x, y){x + y}`

Comment: Thanks Benjamin - that works (but edit it to `'%+=%' <- function(x, y){x <<- x + y}`).  Why not put it as an answer?

Comment: @ChristopherBarry That wouldn't work. Unless you're planning on calling the variable `x` always.

Comment: the idea is more to use a replacement function  like `add<-` <- function(n, value) n+value

Comment: I could be unpopular, but if you feel the need of such operator, very likely you are doing things not much R-ish. Good R programmers don't miss this operator. I can't remember last time I wrote the line `i<-i+1` in R, while `i++` or similar are omnipresent in many other languages.

Comment: Another useful thing might be adding an element to the end of a vector or data frame of arbitrary length without having to write its name twice.  And sorry for the duplicate question - didn't come up when I searched.  The answer appears to be `'%+=%' = function(e1,e2) eval.parent(substitute(e1 <- e1 + e2))`.